# Ajax reload table on X minutes return unknown

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load all data in a table and periodically check if some data is removed and/or added and update the table. It sounds a simple task but I can't make it work.

The problem is that I don't get anything inside `<tbody id='result'></tbody>`. In the console I see the correct response from PHP. So far I have this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {                  
    $.ajax({
      url:'db.php',
      dataType:'json',
      type:'get',
      success:json,
    });

    function json(data){
      $("#result").empty();
      $(data).each(function(index, value)  {
        var table = '<tr><td>' + value.test_name + '</td><td>' + value.test_number + '</td><td>' + value.test_spec + '</td></tr>';
        $('#data').append( table );
      });
    }
  }, 9000);
});
```

```html
<table class="table" id="data">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Spec</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='result'></tbody>
</table>
```

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test_data";
$data = $db_con->query($sql);
$data->execute();

foreach($data as $row))
{   
    echo "<tr>
        <td align=center>'".$row['test_id']."'</td>
        <td align=center>'".$row['test_name']."'</td>
        <td align=center>'".$row['test_number']."'</td>
        <td align=center>'".$row['test_spec']."'</td>
    </tr>";
}
```

This is the output:

```
<tr>
    <td align=center>'1'</td>
    <td align=center>'Test 1'</td>
    <td align=center>'1'</td>
    <td align=center>'EAZ334'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align=center>'2'</td>
    <td align=center>'Test 2'</td>
    <td align=center>'2'</td>
    <td align=center>'EAZ332'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align=center>'3'</td>
    <td align=center>'Test 3'</td>
    <td align=center>'3'</td>
    <td align=center>'EAZ331'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align=center>'4'</td>
    <td align=center>'Test 4'</td>
    <td align=center>'4'</td>
    <td align=center>'EAZ339'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align=center>'5'</td>
    <td align=center>'Test 5'</td>
    <td align=center>'5'</td>
    <td align=center>'EAZ337'</td>
</tr>
```

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

Comment: I'm confused, does your API call return HTML or JSON?

Comment: I'm confused too. I've tried this from tutorial and I'm not sure which why is better?

Comment: @thebluefox, Seems it's returning html judging by the console response log..

Comment: Yep, but your code is set up to handle JSON. You simply need to append the response you recieve into `#results` - which is your `<tbody>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server side code is returning HTML not JSON. So you just need to replace the contents of your table with the response from your sever:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {                  
        $.ajax({
            url: 'db.php',
            type: 'get',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            },
        });
    }, 9000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't show anything either. It doesn't even refresh the table.

Comment: I can't help you with that one - you need to make sure the `url` property in the jQuery AJAX request is correct.

Comment: Okay, I've managed to get it almost work. Just one question.. why I've got all columns in results when I selecting only those three: name, number and spec

Comment: Also it doesn't add new content if there is anything new in database

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `$('#data').append( table );` use 
`$('#result').html( table );`

update your jquery each loop like this. First, build whole HTML string & at the end update that whole HTML string by using "ID".

```
var table = '';
$(data).each(function(index, value)  {
    table += '<tr><td>' + value.test_name + '</td><td>' + value.test_number + '</td><td>' + value.test_spec + '</td></tr>';
});

$('#data').append( table );
```

Comment: Thanks but like this I get only 1 result on page and the result is `UNKNOWN`. On console I see them all

Comment: I'm still getting this `undefined` on each row/cell

Comment: Then, i think... your ```each()``` is not working properly. Check the ```data``` variable structure & use those ``` value.test_name```  &  ```value.test_number``` properly.

Comment: What you mean by properly? Is there another way instead of using `each()` function?

Comment: I mean, may be your ```data``` variable structure is different. That why when you are using ```value.test_name``` it's can't able to pick the require data. use ```console.log()``` or ```JSON.stringify(obj)``` to see the structure

Comment: Thanks for the help. The other answer is helped me to get it work. And is a bit cleaner one.